# Tax implication receiving a payment in US from a company

Tags: united-states, taxes, payment

I want to sell a property located in Asia. The buyer for whatever random reason wants to pay a part of the payment (500k usd) from a US corp account. I do have a personal US bank account, that is, it would be easy to get $500K wire from them and then wire the funds to my account in Europe.
What would be the implications of doing such transfer? Would I need to deal with the IRS (eg file taxes) or even pay some share of the funds? I’m not a US tax person, not a US citizen.

Comment: Sounds like a money laundering/embezzlement scheme. Not a tax issue as much as a criminal one.

Comment: I don’t care if they want to launder/embezzle something. I got a strange offer and part of it $500K to be wired from a US corp account. I want to check if I’m ok to accept that, it’s not my business to verify if they break any laws by doing that

Comment: it will be when the rightful owner comes after you to return the money

Comment: How so? Do you mean they outright steal the money from the company? As I understood it’s their US-based inc and they offered to pay to a US-based corp account, which I do not have (but I have a personal bank account).

Comment: *Do you mean they outright steal the money from the company* - how do you know they're not? Why would their company pay you for their own personal acquisition? That makes no sense.

Comment: Why would I care!? Are you for real, that’s none of my business ‍♂️

Comment: Afaik, the buyer is the corp owner. The question isn’t about validity/legality of their motives, but about issues I could have accepting such payment (specifically issues with IRS and nothing else).

Comment: As I said, the main issue I think you'd have would be with the law enforcement. So it should most definitely be your business. Possessing stolen property *is* a crime almost universally, especially if you had reason to suspect that the property is stolen (which you most certainly do).

Comment: The fact that they're "the owner" of the company is meaningless. Usually embezzlement is done by insiders, that's the difference between embezzlement and theft. If you sold the property to person X and receive payment from Company Y - you should be alarmed. Why would company Y pay you and not person X? If he had the right to take the money - he'd take it to his own account and then paid you properly. Knowingly ignoring warning signs is only going to get you deeper in trouble when this all hits the fan.

Comment: Well, wiring to themselves would mean they’d have to pay like 30% tax or whatever. They probably want to pass it on ex an expense or whatever without first moving funds to personal account. That’s how I understood why they want to do that. It would be up to then to deal with the IRS when they report the corp expense

Comment: So on top of embezzlement you're also a knowing complicit in a tax fraud scheme? Wonderful... Does your home country have no laws against theft and possession of stolen property?

Comment: Let’s rephrase: they want to pay $500k of the entire amount from a corp account. Relative portion of the property would become property of the corp that paid for it. What’s so complicated about it?.. all I want to know if I could have issues accepting the payment

Comment: In the country where it’s done it’s a common scheme. No worries about it.

Comment: Lets simply assume that the corp does it all legally in the US. All I want to know if I could have issues with the IRS accepting such payment. That’s all

Comment: *I’m not a US citizen (and I’ve never been one), I left the US years ago* - why do you care about the IRS?

Comment: Well, I get a 500k wire in my personal account. Perhaps it gets reported to the IRS (no clue about it). I don’t want to file any taxes and pay $500 for that to say that it wasn’t some sort of pay for work or whatever.

Comment: If the company reports is as a tax-deductible expense then yes, it's possible, since the IRS may consider it a US-sourced income. If you're willing to take the risk (which it seems like you are), then the tax issue will be the lower priority issue, the criminal case against you may be more problematic. It may bite you if you end up ever coming back to the US. It may not if the government decides you're not worth the effort.